# Doubling the vowels in a string

Tags: c++

I have to make a program that doubles each vowel in the string. I wrote the following function in which each letter is taken separately and is verified if it is vocal. If so, the whole string will be copied to the next position, thus leaving the vowel in the selected position. The next position will be ocupied by the doubled vowel so i need to skip it. I mention that I have to use only the two strings already declared.

In some examples it works but most of the times, at the last word, it starts to remove consonants or add more vowels. I suspect it has something to do with the position reading after the modification. I tried to rewrite it but it is the same. Sorry for bad english.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char string[200], vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int position;
    cin.get(string, 200);
    for (position = 0; position < strlen(string); position++)
        if (strchr(vowels, string[position]) != 0)
        {
            strcpy(string + position + 1, string + position);
            position++;
        }
    cout << string;
    return 0;
}
```

For example, it needs to show the follwing: Thiis iis aan eexaamplee, but instead it shows: Thiis iis aanneeeexmppplllgw)

Comment: `std::strcpy` doesn't handle strings that overlap. So copying the tail of your string on top of itself won't work. You need to do that copy yourself, starting at the end of the string and working backwards so that you don't overwrite the characters that you haven't copied yet.

Comment: `memmove` may also help  (handles overlapping blocks) but you have to supply the size to move.

Comment: @PeteBecker alternative would be to use `std::memmove`

Comment: Note that because the string keeps changing length, `strlen` becomes a moving target and gets expensive. You might want to just look for the null terminator yourself. Also no defense against the string being extended by vowel doubling past the allocated 200 character limit.

Comment: I can't use memmove, i didn't learn it yet. As for the counter measure for the character limit that is introduced, it is specified that it needs to be 100 or less so i double it. And sorry if i'm a little slow but i don't understand how the backwards thing works.

Comment: @Blazeky *I can't use memmove, i didn't learn it yet* -- Well, isn't it a good time to learn how to use it?  Also, we have no idea what you have or have not learned.  When asking a question on a forum such as StackOverflow, it is assumed you can use whatever is available to a C++ programmer, unless you specify in detail what you cannot use.

Comment: I am conditioned to only use strchr, strlen and strcpy. Even if I know how memmove works I still can't use it.

Comment: That's funny in a sad way. `strlen` and `strcpy` are both nearly useless in this task unless you make the output in a new buffer.

Comment: You can declare a new e.g `string2[200]` then copy each character of `string` to it and double the vowel each time it meets at `position`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string`? If so, that would make things so much easier: `#include <string> int main() { string str; cin >> str; string::size_type position = 0; while ((position = str.find_first_of("aeiouAEIOU", position)) != string::npos) { str.insert(position+1, 1, str[position]); position += 2; } cout << str; return 0; }`

Comment: The question is tagged with C++. The C++ solution is a one liner. ````#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main()
{
 std::string text{ "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" };
 std::cout << std::regex_replace(text, std::regex(R"([aeiouAEIOU])"), R"($&$&)");
 return 0;
}
```` Including ````string.h```` indicates a C program.